# Unit Tests, Build Configuration and Internals

Tags: c#, unit-testing, buildconfiguration

I am writing my UnitTests in a seperate Project from my Project under Test. To be able to test `Internal` classes/members I use the `[InternalsVisibleTo]` Attribute in my Project Under Test.

```
#if "BUILD_CONFIGURATION"
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Tests_ProjectUnderTest")]
#endif
```

Following question arises:

Which Build configuration should I use for Unit Tests? The `Internal`s shouldn't be visible in my released code, so `#if RELEASE` is not possible. On the other hand `#if DEBUG` doesn't really test what I want to release.
Should you have a distinct `UNIT_TEST`-Configuration? Or how would/do you do this?

Comment: Just leave the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in there all the time.  At the end of the day, if people want to get at your internals, they can do it through reflection anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't usually make the `[InternalsVisibleTo()]` attribute conditional, since the internals are only ever made visible to the named assembly. You can beef up the security of that by strong-naming the assemblies, so then no-one can 'fake' your unit test assembly. However, if you're *that* concerned about this, you should probably be obfuscating your assemblies anyway, otherwise reverse engineering is trivial. I generally take the attitude that private/internal is a statement of intent and not a security feature, since it can always be circumvented using reflection.

I generally unit-test my debug configuration, because I want to see the diagnostic output in my unit test results. This may depend on which runner you use, I use the ReSharper runner and it captures debug/trace output into the unit test window. Since the trace verbosity is reduced in my release builds, I prefer to unit test the debug builds. I think this is a judgement call, though.